# Function executes successfully in Remix but fails to execute from angular frontend webapp using Web3

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have following function in smart contract (**already deployed on Goerli Testnet**) which executes correctly from remix IDE and transactions are successful

```
function joinContest(uint256 amount) external payable notPaused {
        require(amount > 0, "Must send ether with the transaction");
        
        // Transfer the amount to the specified address (0xdf81F16559613C4D9769f41157a53a03BE9f8fE1)
        payable(0xdf81F16559613C4D9769f41157a53a03BE9f8fE1).transfer(amount);

    }
```

But when I invoke the same function from my frontend webapp built on Angular using web3, transactions are getting failed.

This is my implementation in angular app:

```
async payForContest(amount: number): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const amountInWei = this.web3.utils.toWei(amount.toString(), 'ether');

      // Estimate gas usage
      const estimatedGas = await this.contract.methods.joinContest(amountInWei).estimateGas({
        from: this.web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress,
        value: amountInWei
      });

      // Send the transaction with the specified gas limit
      const receipt = await this.contract.methods.joinContest(amountInWei).send({
        from: this.web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress,
        value: amountInWei,
        gas: estimatedGas
        // Add other transaction parameters as needed
      });

      // Handle the transaction receipt as needed
      console.log('Transaction Receipt:', receipt);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Pay for Contest error:', error);
      // Handle error
    }
  }
```

Above function is being called like this - `this.payForContest(0.0035);`

Smart Contract - https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xd33d2518a27809f7d2fcda7d05d39da035c9e449
Successful Tx from Remix - https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x7b9405589a0ca6134b99e276d6249c111a590a73c62e8dad46956cf67d0f016b
Failed Tx from frontend - https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x1c4d98dca4534c0e96f6a51bb54e79f251eeafa3215e522a9ac562cbdee5b4d1

Any help in identifying the cause or any pointers on how to debug this issue will be greatly appreciated.